# Adicionar linha automaticamente

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, script

Eu queria uma script sql ou função do excel que percorre a linha e quando encontrar "Out of Compliance" me adicione uma nova linha

```
    Name        Food from Approved Source (C)   Food Protected from Contamination (C)       
16 HANDLES      Out of Compliance                             Out of Compliance
```

nessa nova linha teria:

```
         Name       Violation       
      16 HANDLES    Food from Approved Source (C)         
      16 HANDLES    Food Protected from Contamination (C)
```

Comment: Ola. Adicione ou substitua a linha? Esta a usar `VBA`? Fala de `SQL`, os dados vem de uma base de dados? Quando e que quer que a adição/substituição aconteça? Na base de dados ou no documento excel?

Comment: os dados estão em excel, mas são 50000 linhas. era preferivel que acontecesse no excel. No entanto posso importar para uma base de dados e tratar através de query sql

Comment: Não entendi como tem que ficar a nova linha.